# How can I enable the Task List in Eclipse for a Java Project?

Tags: java, eclipse

My TODO tasks are not showing up automatically in Eclipse. I'm using Eclipse Helios Service Release 2.

I have a standard Java project. Eclipse detects my // TODO and /* TODO */ tasks, because it displays the task icon to the left of the correct source code line. But the Task List pane is empty. The filter is empty, and I have it set to show All.

I also double-checked Window - Preferences - Java - Task List to make sure it was enabled.

Any clue how to make the Task List work?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You have to open the ***Tasks*** view (`Window -> Show View -> (Other... -> General ->) Tasks`) and not the *Task List* view
(differences are explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2081609/367285)).

Comment: D'oh! Wow I feel like a noob now. Wait, how do I do that? You can tell I'm a seasoned Eclipse user, huh?

Comment: Found it. Wow that UI design is terrible. Thx though.

Comment: @retrodrone That's indeed a pitfall!

Comment: Isn't it always a "pitfall" for larger apps? Take a look at Photoshop, 3D max, Dreamweaver. If there are lots of things to choose from and customize then there are a lot of layers in the UI. Of course, things could be a bit more optimized but let's take this case: if you want everything to show up in the "show view" then we need bigger screens or very good glasses. One could always opt for notepad but that does not have task tag functionality like this, so rather then a pitfall one could say "you asked for it" choosing Eclipse over notepad.