# Eclipse plugin to turn TODO and FIXME comments into tasks

Tags: java, eclipse

Is there a plugin in Eclipse that will allow comments with

```
// TODO:
```

and

```
// FIXME:
```

To show up in as task list, like in the "Task List" tab

Comment: This should already occur.

Comment: It does already occur - but you need to open the "Task View", not the (separate) "Task List Tab".  Another good link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081609/eclipse-difference-between-the-tasks-view-and-the-task-list-view

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok thanks for the comments I got, I figured out:

From within Eclipse:

Click: `Windows->Show View->Other...`

Then from the popup dialog select `Tasks`

Then all the TODO and FIXME showed up on the bottom pane.

Comment: thanks for the tip. Just found out we have 284 FIXME's open. :-/

Comment: @pimpf0r no problem... thanks to the comments on my question